# curl page effect in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, page-curl

I have a menu card sort of thing for my hidden object game. In which I  want to add that page curl effect thing which we see in some pdf viewer. 
Whenever user touches it starts that effect and at some point of time it turns the page.

How should I go ahead with that in cocos2dx ?

Is there any pre function to carry out the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the CCTransitionPageTurn scene transition? This might do the trick. You may show a "page curl" sprite when the user touch the screen and then do the actual page turn transition when he releases the touch.

Class reference: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d6/ddb/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_transition_page_turn.html

Comment: i tried that but i want user's continous touch and the effects should work with respect to its touches

Comment: AFAIK there's no out-of-the box cocos2dx feature for what you're looking for. There's a bunch of api out there for page curl effect but mostly for iOS though. Please have a look at those api dor [andoid](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl), for iOS [here](http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/) and [here](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl). You might want to implement something yourself using [opengl] (http://wdnuon.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html)